# good django source browser app?

Tags: django, svn

I need that works at least with svn, that reads your svn repository and displays information about files and folders contained in it as well as maybe revision info too.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of them outhere :(

Answer (score 1):

Does [django-svnlit](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-svnlit/0.1) fit the bill?

Comment: It's kinda buggy - I've tried it on a bunch of repos with all sources of exceptions generated =(

Comment: :o( How about seeing if there are bits of Trac [http://trac.edgewall.org/] you can repurpose? (licences permitting, of course)